# Woocommerce autofill Contract Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the fields belonging to the user on my sales contract page to be filled automatically if the user is logged in.

I used the codes below, but I cannot retrieve the information on the sales contract page because the user has not entered a new invoice information although he is a member.

```
    function wooc_extra_register_fields() {?>
       <p class="form-row form-row-first">
       <label for="billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-last">
       <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

The code I used to get the data into the sales contract

```
<?php
  global $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user();
  echo $current_user->billing_first_name
?>
```

I tried only `echo $current_user->first_name` but it don't work too.

Comment: This fields appear only when the user is not logged in, so you can't get the current user in registration form.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the variable before using it? That method doesn't automatically fill the `$current_user`.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

echo $current_user->user_firstname;
```

See [WordPress function `wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)

Comment: actually this is exactly what I want;

The first time the user enters the site, adds the product to the basket, and the website redirects him to woocommerce's invoice adding page even though he is not a member. Here we can think of the invoice adding page as a membership page. However, this page where the information is entered should be added to the invoice information in order to be filled automatically on the sales contract page.

in short; I entered the website, added a product to the cart, the website will redirect me to the invoice add page.